# Call a javascript function with arguments as an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to execute a function from a string along with an array which should be treated as multiple arguments.

Example:

```
var app = {
  bar : function(val1, val2, val4){
    console.log(val1+val2+val3);
  }
};

fn_name = "bar";
fn_args = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

app[fn_name](fn_args);
```

The issue with this code is that the `fn_args` is being passed as one single argument rather than spread as separate arguments, Is there a work around? i still want to pass `fn_name` and `fn_args` dynamically.

Comment: instead of val1,val2, val3. you can use single argument `args` and use that inside bar function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `apply` method:

```
app[fn_name].apply(app, fn_args);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 1):

Use `function.apply()`.

```
app[fn_name].apply(app, fn_args);
```

The first arguument is the context (`this`) inside the function, and the second is the array whose items should be passed as arguments.